# Errors by calculating median in R

Tags: r, mean, median

I just want to calculate the mean/median of all the values in my table. I tried several functions but nothing seems to work, I'm always getting errors like 'Argument is not nummeric or Logical: returning NA' or 'object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

I have a table consisting of 11 columns. I have several NA's in my data.

I tried the following:

```
mean(WDB1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Didn't work so I thought Maybe `as.numeric` will help:

```
as.numeric(WDB1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I also tried to build a dataframe and to use `apply`.

The output from str(WDB1) is:

```
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Artname: Factor w/ 18 levels "Andrena carotonica",..: 11 9 10 7 8 12 15 14 1 3 ...
 $ X1     : int  2 0 7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X2     : int  4 1 41 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X3     : int  27 7 39 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X4     : int  37 5 32 NA 7 2 NA 1 NA NA ...
 $ X5     : int  38 3 33 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X6     : int  35 12 33 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X7     : int  12 4 44 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X8     : int  12 15 24 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X9     : int  30 0 39 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X10    : int  18 2 33 1 NA NA NA NA 1 NA ...
```

dput(WDB1)

```
structure(list(Artname = structure(c(11L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
15L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 17L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 6L), .Label = c("Andrena carotonica", 
"Andrena cineraria", "Andrena dorsata", "Andrena flavipes", "Andrena nigriceps", 
"Anthopora plumipes", "Bombus hortorum", "Bombus humilis", "Bombus lapidarius", 
"Bombus lucorum", "Bombus pascuorum", "Bombus pratorium", "Colletes similis", 
"Heriades truncorum", "Lasioglossum punctatissimum", "Lasioglosum lucidulum", 
"Melitta haemorrhoridales", "Sphecodes puncticeps"), class = "factor"),

    X1 = c(2L, 0L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), X2 = c(4L, 1L, 41L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), X3 = c(27L, 
    7L, 39L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), X4 = c(37L, 5L, 32L, NA, 7L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L), X5 = c(38L, 3L, 33L, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), X6 = c(35L, 12L, 33L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), X7 = c(12L, 4L, 44L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X8 = c(12L, 
    15L, 24L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), X9 = c(30L, 0L, 39L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X10 = c(18L, 2L, 33L, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I'm new to R and really thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What is the output of `str(WDB1)`? Please add that information to the question text.

Comment: There are probably some strings in your data

Comment: @Roland, I added the output, unfortunately it is not as ordered as in the editor box.

Comment: And for what would you like the mean? Rows, columns, ...

Comment: Since your data is extremely small, please add the output of dput(WDB1) since that enables us to easily reproduce it.

Comment: You are currently asking R to calculate the mean/median of a data frame. Do you want the mean/median of each column/row/or of all values contained in your data.frame?

Comment: @OTStats I already have the mean/median of each column. Now I Need it from all values in my dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already have the mean/median of each column. Now I Need it from all
>   values in my dataframe.

Presumably, that means the mean of all columns except the first one (which is a factor column).

The steps for doing that are:

Subset the data.frame to remove the first column:

```
WDB1[,-1]
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#1   2  4 27 37 38 35 12 12 30  18
#2   0  1  7  5  3 12  4 15  0   2
#3   7 41 39 32 33 33 44 24 39  33
#4  NA NA  5 NA  2 NA NA NA NA   1
#5  NA NA NA  7 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#6  NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#8  NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA   1
#10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#11 NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#12  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA   1
#13 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA   1
#14  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#15  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
#16  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA   1
#17 NA  1 NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA  NA
#18 NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA   1
```

Transform the result into a vector because `mean` doesn't except data.frames as input. I use `unlist` because data.frame's are lists, but you also could use `as.matrix`:

```
unlist(WDB1[,-1])
# X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19  X110  X111  X112  X113  X114  X115  X116  X117  X118   X21   X22   X23   X24   X25   X26 
#    2     0     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA     2     1     1    NA    NA     4     1    41    NA    NA    NA 
#  X27   X28   X29  X210  X211  X212  X213  X214  X215  X216  X217  X218   X31   X32   X33   X34   X35   X36   X37   X38   X39  X310  X311  X312 
#   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    27     7    39     5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 
# X313  X314  X315  X316  X317  X318   X41   X42   X43   X44   X45   X46   X47   X48   X49  X410  X411  X412  X413  X414  X415  X416  X417  X418 
#   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    37     5    32    NA     7     2    NA     1    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3 
#  X51   X52   X53   X54   X55   X56   X57   X58   X59  X510  X511  X512  X513  X514  X515  X516  X517  X518   X61   X62   X63   X64   X65   X66 
#   38     3    33     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    35    12    33    NA    NA    NA 
#  X67   X68   X69  X610  X611  X612  X613  X614  X615  X616  X617  X618   X71   X72   X73   X74   X75   X76   X77   X78   X79  X710  X711  X712 
#   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    12     4    44    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 
# X713  X714  X715  X716  X717  X718   X81   X82   X83   X84   X85   X86   X87   X88   X89  X810  X811  X812  X813  X814  X815  X816  X817  X818 
#   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    12    15    24    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 
#  X91   X92   X93   X94   X95   X96   X97   X98   X99  X910  X911  X912  X913  X914  X915  X916  X917  X918  X101  X102  X103  X104  X105  X106 
#   30     0    39    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    18     2    33     1    NA    NA 
# X107  X108  X109 X1010 X1011 X1012 X1013 X1014 X1015 X1016 X1017 X1018 
#   NA    NA     1    NA    NA     1     1    NA    NA     1    NA     1
```

Pass the vector to the `mean` function (make sure to deal with `NA` values by setting `na.rm = TRUE`):

```
mean(unlist(WDB1[,-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 12.2549
```

Comment: Ah it finally worked. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake.

You're calculating the mean/median over a data frame.

You have to calculate it over each variable using `$` symbol.

Something like this.

```
mydf

Var1 Var2
1     1
1     2
2     3
4     20
```

Then if I want to get the median of `Var1` I write `median(mydf$Var1)`

To do it for all variables at once use `for` loop.

```
vector.median<-c()
vector.mean<-c()
for(i in ncol(mydf)){
vector.median[i]<-median(as.numeric(mydf[,i]),na.rm=TRUE)
vector.mean[i]<-mean(as.numeric(mydf[,i]),na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Then, `vector.median` stores the medians and `vector.mean` stores the means.

Comment: But isn't there a way where I can just calculate it for all my values? I already have it for the ten different variables but now I want to have the median/mean from the whole table combined.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but I'm also just getting the result NA, NA, NA …

Comment: Did you put `na.rm=TRUE` ?

Comment: Yes I did. I also got a new value next to the two vectors: i   11L. Maybe it's because of the species names in column 1? Do I need to exclude them?

Comment: That means you're working with integers, use `as.numeric`.

Comment: Still no Change with the NAs :(

Comment: I did it with your data frame and it worked, for the first variable I got `mean=3` and `median=2`, check your code, please.

Comment: I did. I have exactly the same code. I think I messed something up with my table and the species names. Thank you so much for your help! I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: Yeah, I can't help you further, there's no reason to recive NA's anymore. Try excluding variables with character class if there's anyone, use `class` function by column.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you have provided, you can use `dplyr` functions to filter for numeric columns, then you can use `tidyr` to get all your columns in one row, and lastly you can summarize.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  summarise(median_value = median(value, na.rm = TRUE), 
            mean_value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))

#  median_value mean_value
#1            4    12.2549
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. My output is just     #1     NA   NA,
I have tried it with 'na.rm = T', but it is still just NA

Comment: I used the data you provided in your question and I got 4 and 12.25, for median and mean respectively. Without seeing your actual data it's hard to help.